# Align range slider and label

Tags: html, css, slider

I am trying to align vertically html range slide and a label displaying current value. 
The problem is if label font size is larger than 100% it is not aligned. Tried both 'label' and 'output'

HTML

```
<div>
<output id="myoutput" class="lblFloat">Output: 50</output>
<label for="myslider" id="mylabel" class="lblFloat">Label: 50</label>
<input type="range" id="myslider" min="1" max="100" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.lblFloat
{
float:right;
font-size: 200%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sergeyvin/1v19t4no/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `table-cell`:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse; /* or 'row' and change the order of your html elements */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end; /* or 'flex-start' and change the order of your html elements */
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tupupawg/

Comment: Well he can also use other values for justify-content property but ok, overall this solution is a desired result.